# Problem with active directory authentication in linux container

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have .Net Core 3.1 MVC project in linux container. I deployed it on Azure App Service and setup Azure Active Directory authentication. Local everything work good, but on server I have a problem "The reply URL specified in the request does no match the reply URLs confiqured for the application". As I see AD returnUrl = http://site.azurewebsites.net, but I setup Redirect Urls like https://site.azurewebsites.net

My Azure Active Directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQK2J.png)
My App Service Authentication
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0W7X.png)

Answer (score 0):

- This issue could be resolved once you have **same URLS** at both places
  in app registration and also make sure to **clear** cache.(Also check if the **protocol** for both uris is same i.e;**Https**)
- You can see the reply url/redirect uri during sign-in /Authentication
  request in the address bar of the browser on the error screen
  (Recommended to use Chrome or Edge browser).If it is SAML request,
  Assertion Consumer Service represents the reply url.
  [image]

> **Something in below format For OpenId Connect:**
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=76f00765-7657-66hg-ag19-34s653ad0a65&redirect_uri=https://www.contoso.com/signin-oidc

[image]

- So check if this redirect uri  of your app(in the authentication
  request which maybe present in helper class of your application )
  **matches**  redirect uri in AAD  in app registration URI .If not ,correct it or add it.  See if callback path in appsettings.json is
  “/signin-oidc” as url must be in “/signin-oidc” format
- If You have url in app registration like say>>https://localhost:44324/signin-oidc,
  then you must be testing it from local machine which is running on 443
- Since its working locally and issue is only with Server, it may be due to https 443 firewall block.So try to **Allow** 443 port (on test server) and
  try the mentioned steps.

If you want to determine what is the redirect uri present you may try in [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) .

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, a blazor server app hosted in an azure linux app service container:

Configured forward header options. (someone somewhere mentioned that this works only with windows..)

```
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
         {

             options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;

             // Only loopback proxies are allowed by default.
             // Clear that restriction because forwarders are enabled by explicit
             // configuration.
             options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
             options.KnownProxies.Clear();

         });
```

AD Auth Configured:

```
        services
              .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
              //.AddOpenIdConnect()
              .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), subscribeToOpenIdConnectMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true);

        services
            .AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services
            .AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });
```

Web App configured:

```
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        ...
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Had this environment variable to the dockerfile

```
        ENV ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED=true
```

Finally, added the same env var as a configuration value of app-service, through bicep:

```
appSettings: union(appSettings, [
  {
    name: 'DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL'
    value: 'https://${acrLoginServer}'
  }
  {
    name: 'DOCKER_ENABLE_CI'
    value: 'true' 
  }
  {
    name: 'ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED'
    value: 'true' 
  }
])
```